# What do you call staff groups at University departments?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

At my university, many departments comprise several subjects, so, for instance, the Department of Languages comprise English, French, German etc. Now I'm wondering how you would refer collectively to the staff working with a specific subject – for instance, in sentences such as the following, what do I use instead of XXX to refer collectively to the staff working with a certain subject? Could I just say "the subject"? Or perhaps "the subject meeting"? Or "the subject assembly"? Or something else entirely?

> The Dean will consult with XXX, and then either approve or reject the application.

> XXX will discuss the matter in two consecutive meetings.

Thank you!

Comment: Anecdotally, if there isn't a formal subdivision, I generally hear them called e.g., "the German group" or "the German staff" or "the German unit". 'Unit' might be a less common usage, as the term may also be used as a synonym for 'credit' or for 'module'.

Comment: If by "staff" you mean the people teaching the courses, then it's the "departmental faculty."

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Thank you! These would work in cases where you know which group you're talking about, but what do you use if you don't? That is, when you want to say something about such staff groups in general?

Comment: @CanadianYankee Thank you! But what if it's only the teaching staff within a single subject within a department? The subject faculty? (sounds a bit odd...)

Comment: A lot of colleges just make up their own terms for things like this. For example, I know one that calls it a SAC (Subject Area Committee), but this is not a standard term across all colleges.

Comment: @Helen - The [name of subject] faculty - for example, "the German faculty."

Comment: @CanadianYankee Right, thanks – but what if the subjects remains unspecified, and I just want to refer to any such faculty, regardless of subject, shall I refer to it as "subject faculty" then?

Comment: @Helen - "Subject faculty" sounds a little clumsy.  You could use a longer phrase like "faculty for each subject," which isn't concise, but I think it's pretty rare that you'd want to refer to such a group while leaving the subject itself unspecified.

Comment: @CanadianYankee Thank you! No, it's probably not the most common situation, but it's nevertheless one I find myself in at the moment... I'm translating a text that is, in fact, littered with sentences where I need to refer to this... Perhaps I could use "the faculty for the subject concerned"? or "the faculty for the relevant subject"?